# Do suits matter in Double board poker

Tags: hand-history

Playing in a home game. Double board Omaha.  I imagine it would be the same for Hold em too. We played best high and best low out of the two boards.  One player had Ace high flush in clubs on one board.  This player had Ace and King of clubs in his hand. The other player had Ace high flush on the other board  his Ace was on the board. His flush was Hearts.  Player with hearts claims hearts are higher so he wins. Player with clubs claims since Ace is his high card (or king) he wins. He is also agreeable to a split. There was no low hand.  Who is right. It was a huge pot for this home game

Answer (score -1):

the player with hearts, was full of BS. there is no such commmon rule. not tosay the players did not have such a house rule.

Comment: Is it a split then?   Or is is it high

Comment: High card in the players hand?

Comment: IT IS SIMPLE AND BASIC, BEST FIVE CARDS WIN. SUITS DO NOT MATTER DETERMINING THE TIE BREAKER AS YOU THINK. THE ONLY TIME SUITSS IN POKER HAVE EVER MATTERED IS FOR THE BRING IN WITH SEVEN CARD STUD.